# How to remove the need to press a button on Photoshop Script

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I am trying to automate  the process of:

Creating a text layer with the name of the file written on it.

I got a code that helped me to active this almost 100%. I did small changes to the code so now I don't need a Dialog box to appear.

**The problem is:** I can't fully automatize the process due to the need of clicking the OK button.

**The Solution I need is:** Automatically press the button, OR not even show the confirmation box.

Here is the code I have:

```
// enable double-clicking from Mac Finder or Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// bring application forward for double-click events
app.bringToFront();

if ( documents.length > 0 ){prefs = setPreferences(); main()}else{alert("ERROR!!!!!\nSeems we dont have any file open. \nNothing to do. :) \nOpen a file and try again.")}

function setPreferences(){
 var prefs = new Object();
/* EDIT STARTS HERE */
prefs.textFromBottom = 240;
prefs.startOffsetFromLeft = 369;
prefs.fontSize = '40px';
/* EDIT ENDS HERE */

 prefs.incPath =true;prefs.incExt =true;prefs.originalDialogMode = app.displayDialogs;prefs.originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits; app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
return prefs;
}

function process(){var origDoc = activeDocument;var fullName = origDoc.name; if(!prefs.incExt){fullName = fullName.replace(/(?:\.[^.]*$|$)/, ''); }if(prefs.incPath){fullName = origDoc.path.toString() + ":: " + fullName;}var myLayerRef = origDoc.artLayers.add();myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;myLayerRef.name = fullName;var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;myTextRef.position = new Array( prefs.startOffsetFromLeft, origDoc.height - prefs.textFromBottom );myTextRef.size = prefs.fontSize; myTextRef.contents = myLayerRef.name;}
function main(){try{setOptions();process();}catch( e ){/* An error occurred. Restore ruler units, then propagate the error back to the user */preferences.rulerUnits = prefs.originalRulerUnits;app.displayDialogs = prefs.originalDialogMode;throw e;}}
function setOptions(){ 

#target estoolkit

var win, windowResource;windowResource = "dialog {orientation: 'column', alignChildren: ['fill', 'top'],preferredSize:[350, 180], text: 'Photoshop Script - Insert FileName (TextLayer)',margins:10, settingPanel: Group { orientation: 'column',fontSize: Group { st4: StaticText { text: 'Select Font Size:' }, sl: Slider { minvalue: 10, maxvalue: 50, value: 40, size:[200,20] }, quality: StaticText { text: '25px', characters: 4} },incPath: Checkbox { text:'Include Path', value: false }, incExt: Checkbox { text:'Include Extension', value: false}, applyButton: Button { text: 'Insert»', properties:{name:'ok'},size:[350,30] , weight:bold }, dummy:StaticText { text: '' },alignChildren: 'left',} creditGroup: Group { orientation: 'row', alignChildren: 'right', linkText:StaticText { text: 'Visit us: www.tejwani.com/photoshop-scripting/' }, } }"
win = new Window(windowResource); /* listen and update text box */ win.settingPanel.fontSize.sl.onChange = function() {win.settingPanel.fontSize.quality.text = Math.round(this.value) + 'px';}
/* apply button */win.settingPanel.applyButton.onClick = function() {prefs.fontSize = win.settingPanel.fontSize.quality.text;prefs.incPath =win.settingPanel.incPath.value;prefs.incExt =win.settingPanel.incExt.value;return win.close();};
win.creditGroup.linkText.onClick = function() {File(app.path.toString() + "/Presets/Scripts/TS-insert-filename.html").execute();};win.show();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried `displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;` at the top of your script?

Comment: @GhoulFool Than ks for the comment. My knowledge is veryyy limited. I can kind of read the code and recognize a little the function of it. I tried some changes in the code but it just stop working. I could try what you suggested but I don't know where to do the change. Could you help me on that? I will try but I doubt I will be able to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

The core of the script, taken from [www.tejwani.com](http://www.tejwani.com) is this:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 

// make a reference to the active document
var origDoc = activeDocument;

// get the file name
var fullName = origDoc.name;

// make a new layer
var myLayerRef = origDoc.artLayers.add();

// make it a text layer
myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;

// make the layer name the same as the file name
myLayerRef.name = fullName;

var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

// get the centre of the image
var hw = origDoc.width.value/2;
var hh = origDoc.height.value/2;

// make the position the centre of the image
myTextRef.position  = [hw, hh];

// font size
myTextRef.size = 10.0;

// make the text say the filename
myTextRef.contents = fullName;

// set back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // OFF
```

I'm only doing this as you can crash Photoshop with text, not because this is your first question. Stack Overflow isn't a script writing service. However, if you do run into difficulties just paste your code and explain what you think it should do.